# Overloading conjugate operator for a particular function

Tags: evaluation, complex, downvalues, upvalues

I trying to modify the behaviour of the built-in `Conjugate[]` operator on a particular function I have defined, to take into account that some of its variables are real.

```
ClearAll[f];
f /: Conjugate[f[k_]] := Conjugate[F[r]] Exp[I k r]
f[k_] := F[r] Exp[-I k r]
```

The problem with using `UpValues` in this way is that the `DownValues` for `f[k]` are evaluated before, resulting in:

```
Conjugate[f[k]]=Exp[I Conjugate[k r]] Conjugate[F[r]]
```

Using non-standard evaluation seems to do the trick

```
Conjugate[Unevaluated[f[k]]]=Exp[I k r] Conjugate[F[r]]
```

However, I want to use my function inside expressions like

```
f[k1] + f[k2] + Conjugate[f[k3]]
```

without having to manually replace `f[_]` by `Unevaluated[f[_]]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility would be to define a new `Conjugate` function, `myConjugate`, the behaves in the same way as `Conjugate`, except when it encounters a phase of the type `Exp[+(-)I k r]`, it transforms it to `Exp[-(+)I k r]`, leaving `k` and `r` as real variables.

Another possibility (and the one I ended up using) is to go along the lines of [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648260/what-does-upvalue-mean-in-mathematica-and-when-to-use-them) and use `UpValues` to explicitly define `k` and `r` as being real:

```
ClearAll[makeReal];
makeReal[a__Symbol] := (# /: Conjugate[#] := #) & /@ List[a]

makeReal[k, r]
```

Then one gets the expected

```
Conjugate[F[r] Exp[-I k r]]= Exp[I k r] Conjugate[F[r]]
```

Comment: I always find it amusing when my old answers resurface. :)

Comment: This is a wonderful resolution to get rid of the annoying `Conjugate`!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to define upvalues for `f` nor for your own `myConjugate` function. Using your definitions:

```
ClearAll[F,f];
f[k_] := F[r] Exp[-I k r]
```

all you need to do is tell `Conjugate` to distribute over addition and then `Refine` it by letting Mathematica know which variables are real. So, say you have an expression:

```
Conjugate[f[k1] + f[k2] - Conjugate[f[k3]]]
```

by calling

```
Assuming[{k1 ∈ Reals, k2 ∈ Reals, 
  k3 ∈  Reals, r ∈ Reals}, Refine[Distribute /@ %]]
```

you get the desired (?)

```
E^(I k1 r) Conjugate[F[r]] + E^(I k2 r) Conjugate[F[r]] - 
 E^(-I k3 r) F[r]
```

If `F` is behaving with a known pattern under conjugation you can account for it by changing its `UpValues`, i.e.

```
F /: Conjugate[F[r_]] := F[-r]
```

and the above would still work.

Comment: I am aware that I can use assumptions, but this is not what I want.

Comment: Can you please edit the question to explain a little better what you want then? I can edit my answer to include a `myConjugate` function that ignores phases but you need to be more specific as to how you want it to behave.

Comment: Thanks for accepting but if my answer didn't answer your question the way you intended you really don't have to accept it! In fact there is no harm (I'd say it's encouraged) to write down your own answer and accept it if nobody else comes up with something better within some time. It seems you can write an answer incorporating both your edits.

Comment: Ok @gpap, I followed your advice, hope you don't mind! :)