# How to tell Mathematica that the argument of a function is real?

Tags: function-construction, complex

I want to define the following function in mathematica:
$$R(\psi)=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&\cos 2\psi & \sin 2\psi\\0&-\sin 2\psi & \cos 2\psi\end{bmatrix}\qquad,\psi\in\mathbb R$$ So
$$R(\psi)^{\dagger}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&\cos 2\psi &-\sin 2\psi\\0&\sin 2\psi &\cos 2\psi\end{bmatrix}$$

So far I have tried some codes like:

```
R[ψ_; ψ ∈ Reals] := {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[2 ψ], 
   Sin[2 ψ]}, {0, -Sin[2 ψ], Cos[2 ψ]}}
```

Or:

```
R[ψ_] := {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[2 ψ], 
    Sin[2 ψ]}, {0, -Sin[2 ψ], 
    Cos[2 ψ]}} /; ψ ∈ Reals
```

but running the code:

```
ConjugateTranspose[R[ψ]] // TraditionalForm
```

I get:
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \cos  \left(2 \psi ^*\right) & -\left(\sin  \left(2 \psi ^*\right)\right) \\
 0 & \sin  \left(2 \psi ^*\right) & \cos  \left(2 \psi ^*\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**P.S.** I know that I can use the following code:

```
R[ψ_] := {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[2 ψ], 
   Sin[2 ψ]}, {0, -Sin[2 ψ], Cos[2 ψ]}}  

Refine[ConjugateTranspose[R[ψ]], ψ ∈ 
   Reals] // TraditionalForm
```

but I want to know how to define $R(\psi)$ inherently as a real function?

Comment: You could consider having a global assumption that `psi` is real: `$Assumptions = {Element[ψ, Reals]}`. See also the [documentation for `$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html).

Comment: Is there a particular reason for use `ConjugateTranspose` instead of `Transpose`? Please note: I can't comment yet so take this as a comment. In another "answer" of mine, which was deleted, I was suggested to "comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post." Which I found a pointless advice as I don't want to comment meaningless stuff in order to comment where I want.

Comment: A few basic things:Your conditional syntax is wrong, should be `/;` and `Element` is not a conditional test but an assertion.

Comment: I know that I can use `Transpose` instead of `ConjugateTranspose` but I wanted 1) obey the general notation 2) Learn the concept how to define a functions with variables in certain domains

Comment: note setting `$Assumptions` saves you from adding the assumption to `Refine`, but you still need to use `Refine` or `Simplify` or similar function for the `$Assumption` to be applied.

Comment: @george2079 I know that's not a good solution.

Comment: mathematica does not have a sense of assigning attributes to abstract symbols, except when you instruct specific functions s.a. `Simplify` to treat them a certain way.  You can define a function to take only real *numeric* arguments of course, but I don't think that's what you are after.

Comment: @george2079 you mean there's nothing I can do about it? well, then I decided to use that `Refine` solution and I encountered [another problem](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95969/30689)

Comment: Related: [example in rcollyers answer to "What does “upvalue” mean in Mathematica and when to use them?"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6650884/5400699), [Overloading conjugate operator for a particular function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25372/14303)

Comment: There are [things to do after your question has been answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Its a good idea to stay vigilant some time after you get the first answer, better approaches may come later improving over a previous reply and experienced users may point to caveats. Therefore, new users may **wait 24 hours** before [voting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) the deserving answers and a bit more before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the best one for you. (Links contain useful information)

Answer (score 9):

## Declaring expressions as real

As others have already written you can set global [`$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/%24Assumptions.html), but then to get desired results you would need to, each time, use `Refine`, `Simplify`, or similar function that uses `Assumptions`.

If you want certain expressions to be treated as "real" automatically, without simplifying, you can override behavior of built-in functions like `Conjugate`, `Re`, etc. using [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues.html).

Here is a small package, based on [@rcollyer's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6650884/5400699), that allows us to declare certain patterns as "real".
After declaring pattern as real, *Mathematica* will automatically simplify some expressions involving sub-expressions matching said pattern.
It will also automatically use appropriate global assumptions when simplifying using `Refine`, `Simplify` etc.

```
BeginPackage["DeclareReal`"];
Unprotect["`*"];
ClearAll["`*"];


DeclareReal::usage =
"DeclareReal[patt1, patt2, ...] declares expressions matching patterns patt1, \
patt2, ... as real. Given patterns must contain symbols to which UpValues can \
be assigned.";

UndeclareReal::usage = 
"UndeclareReal[patt1, patt2, ...] removes given patterns patt1, patt2, ... \
from patterns declared as real.";


Begin["`Private`"];
ClearAll["`*"];


symbolWithUpValue[expr_, upValueSubExpr_] :=
    FirstCase[
        expr,
        atom_ /; AtomQ@Unevaluated[atom] :>
            With[
                {sym =
                    Replace[
                        Unevaluated[atom],
                        nonSym:Except[_Symbol] :> Head@Unevaluated[nonSym]
                    ]
                },
                sym /; Head[sym] === Symbol &&
                    !FreeQ[UpValues[sym], upValueSubExpr]
        ],
        Missing["NotFound"],
        All,
        Heads -> True
    ]


extractUpValueTag[patt_] :=
    Module[{dummy, upValueTag, upSetSuccess = True},
        Internal`InheritedBlock[{Message},
            Unprotect[Message];
            Message[UpSet::write, HoldForm[tag_], HoldForm[_dummy]] := (
                upValueTag = tag;
                upSetSuccess = False;
            );
            dummy[patt] ^= dummy;
        ];
        If[upSetSuccess,
            upValueTag = symbolWithUpValue[patt, dummy];
            With[{upValueTag = upValueTag}, upValueTag /: dummy[patt] =.]
        ];
        {upValueTag, upSetSuccess}
    ]


updateAssumptions[oldRealPattern_, newRealPattern_] :=
    Module[{found = False},
        $Assumptions =
            $Assumptions /. 
                Verbatim@Element[oldRealPattern, Reals] :> (
                    found = True; 
                    Element[newRealPattern, Reals]
                );
        If[!found,
            $Assumptions = $Assumptions && Element[newRealPattern, Reals]
        ];
    ]


$realPattern = Alternatives[dummy];


DeclareReal[patt_] :=
    With[{tagSuccessPair = extractUpValueTag[patt]},
        With[{tag = First[tagSuccessPair], success = Last[tagSuccessPair]},
            Condition[
                tag /: Element[patt, Reals] = True;
                tag /: Im[patt] = 0;
                tag /: Re[expr : patt] := expr;
                tag /: Abs[expr : patt] := Sign[expr] expr;
                tag /: Arg[expr : patt] := Piecewise[{{Pi, Sign[expr] < 0}}];
                tag /: Conjugate[expr : patt] := expr;
                updateAssumptions[
                    $realPattern,
                If[MemberQ[$realPattern, Verbatim[patt]],
                        $realPattern
                (* else *),
                    AppendTo[$realPattern, patt]
                    ]
                ];
                tag
                ,
                If[!success,
                    Message[DeclareReal::write,
                        HoldForm@tag, HoldForm@DeclareReal[patt]
                    ]
                ];
                success
            ]
        ]
    ]
DeclareReal[patts : Repeated[_, {2, Infinity}]] := DeclareReal /@ {patts}


UndeclareReal[patt_] :=
    With[{tagSuccessPair = extractUpValueTag[patt]},
        With[{tag = First[tagSuccessPair], success = Last[tagSuccessPair]},
            Condition[
                Quiet[
                    tag /: Element[patt, Reals] =.;
                    tag /: Im[patt] =.;
                    tag /: Re[expr : patt] =.;
                    tag /: Abs[expr : patt] =.;
                    tag /: Arg[expr : patt] =.;
                    tag /: Conjugate[expr : patt] =.;
                    ,
                    TagUnset::norep
                ]
                updateAssumptions[
                    $realPattern,
                $realPattern = DeleteCases[$realPattern, Verbatim[patt]]
                ];
                tag
                ,
                If[!success,
                    Message[UndeclareReal::write,
                        HoldForm@tag, HoldForm@DeclareReal[patt]
                    ]
                ];
                success
            ]
        ]
    ]
UndeclareReal[patts : Repeated[_, {2, Infinity}]] := UndeclareReal /@ {patts}


End[];
Protect["`*"];
EndPackage[]
```

Let's declare some example patterns as real:

```
ClearAll[f, g, x, y, a, b]
DeclareReal[x, f[_], HoldPattern@g[_Integer, _Integer], a + b]
(* DeclareReal::write: Tag Plus in DeclareReal[a+b] is Protected. >> *)
(* {x, f, g, DeclareReal[a + b]} *)
```

`DeclareReal` function returned list of symbols, to which appropriate, `UpValues` where assigned.
`a + b` expression caused an error, because its head is `Plus`, which is protected, and we can't assign upvalue to it.

Since `x` is real its real value is just `x`:

```
Re[x]
(* x *)
```

We declared `f` with one argument as real, but not `f` with two arguments.

```
Im[f[y]]
(* 0 *)
Im[f[x, y]]
(* Im[f[x, y]] *)
```

`g` is real with two integer arguments:

```
Conjugate[g[1, 2]]
(* g[1, 2] *)
Conjugate[g[1, y]]
(* Conjugate[g[1, y]] *)
```

`a+b` expression was not affected

```
Conjugate[a + b]
(* Conjugate[a + b] *)
```

Now let's undo above declarations

```
UndeclareReal[x, f[_], HoldPattern@g[_Integer, _Integer]]
(* {x, f, g} *)
Re[x]
(* Re[x] *)
Im[f[y]]
(* Im[f[y]] *)
Conjugate[g[1, 2]]
(* Conjugate[g[1, 2]] *)
```

---

## Problem from question

Now let's go back to function from question.

```
ClearAll[r]
r[x_] := {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[2 x], Sin[2 x]}, {0, -Sin[2 x], Cos[2 x]}}
```

Check how it behaves for real and complex arguments and arguments for which it doesn't know whether they are real or not.

```
ClearAll[x, ψ]
DeclareReal[ψ];

r[2]
(* {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[4], Sin[4]}, {0, -Sin[4], Cos[4]}} *)
% // ConjugateTranspose
(* {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[4], -Sin[4]}, {0, Sin[4], Cos[4]}} *)

r[2 + I]
(* {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[4 + 2 I], Sin[4 + 2 I]}, {0, -Sin[4 + 2 I], Cos[4 + 2 I]}} *)
% // ConjugateTranspose
(* {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cosh[2 + 4 I], I Sinh[2 + 4 I]}, {0, -I Sinh[2 + 4 I], Cosh[2 + 4 I]}} *)

r[x]
(* {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[2 x], Sin[2 x]}, {0, -Sin[2 x], Cos[2 x]}} *)
% // ConjugateTranspose
(* {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[2 Conjugate[x]], -Sin[2 Conjugate[x]]}, {0, Sin[2 Conjugate[x]], Cos[2 Conjugate[x]]}} *)

r[ψ]
(* {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[2 ψ], Sin[2 ψ]}, {0, -Sin[2 ψ], Cos[2 ψ]}} *)
% // ConjugateTranspose
(* {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[2 ψ], -Sin[2 ψ]}, {0, Sin[2 ψ], Cos[2 ψ]}} *)
```

Note that there's nothing "real" in `r` function, it works for all types of arguments.
What is "real" here is number `2` and `ψ` symbol.

If we really want a "real function", we first need to specify what precisely that means.
Say we want a function which domain is set of real numbers and we expect following behavior. Function should:

- evaluate when *Mathematica* can be sure that argument of function is real,
- fail, with some error message, when *Mathematica* can be sure that arguments of function is not real,
- remain unevaluated when *Mathematica* can't decide whether argument is real or not.

Moreover we want *Mathematica* to know that, for any valid argument, value of function can be considered real (in this particular case matrix of expressions that represent real numbers),
so function in unevaluated form should be considered real.

Above conditions are fulfilled by following function:

```
ClearAll[r]
r::domain = "`1` is not in domain of r function.";
r[x_ /; x ∈ Reals] :=
    {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[2 x], Sin[2 x]}, {0, -Sin[2 x], Cos[2 x]}}
r[x_ /; Not[x ∈ Reals]] := (Message[r::domain, HoldForm[x]]; $Failed)
DeclareReal[HoldPattern@r[_]];

ClearAll[x, ψ]
DeclareReal[ψ];

r[2]
(* {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[4], Sin[4]}, {0, -Sin[4], Cos[4]}} *)
% // Conjugate
(* {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[4], Sin[4]}, {0, -Sin[4], Cos[4]}} *)

r[2 + I]
(* r::domain: 2+I is not in domain of r function. *)
(* $Failed *)
% // Conjugate
(* Conjugate[$Failed] *)

r[x]
(* r[x] *)
% // Conjugate
(* r[x] *)

r[ψ]
(* {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[2 ψ], Sin[2 ψ]}, {0, -Sin[2 ψ], Cos[2 ψ]}} *)
% // Conjugate
(* {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[2 ψ], Sin[2 ψ]}, {0, -Sin[2 ψ], Cos[2 ψ]}} *)
```

Note that even for unevaluated `r[x]` *Mathematica* knows that it's real and its conjugation returns `r[x]`.

Answer (score 3):

If you use numbers you can define

```
R[ψ_Real] := {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[2 ψ], Sin[2 ψ]}, {0, -Sin[2 ψ], Cos[2 ψ]}}
```

For symbolic analysis you will need to use `Simplify` in conjunction with assumptions as indicated by *george2079*.

It would look something like this:

```
R[ψ_] := {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[2 ψ], Sin[2 ψ]}, {0, -Sin[2 ψ], Cos[2 ψ]}}
```

and then

```
Simplify[ConjugateTranspose[R[ψ]], ψ ∈ Reals] // TraditionalForm
```

produces

[image: Mathematica graphics]