# Do not understand the result I'm getting from Solve

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

I did

```
Solve[k2 Cos[x] - k1 Sin[x] == 0,x]
```

Since tangent is sin over cos, the solution must be

```
arctan(k2/k1)
```

But *Mathematica* gives

> ```
> {{x -> 
>      ConditionalExpression[
>        ArcTan[-(k1/Sqrt[k1^2 + k2^2]), -(k2/Sqrt[k1^2 + k2^2])] + 2*Pi*C[1], 
>        Element[C[1], Integers]]}, 
>   {x -> 
>      ConditionalExpression[
>        ArcTan[k1/Sqrt[k1^2 + k2^2], k2/Sqrt[k1^2 + k2^2]] + 2*Pi*C[1], 
>        Element[C[1], Integers]]}}
> ```

Why is this the case?

Comment: Try simplifying this expression assuming `k1` and `k2` are `Reals`.

Comment: Consider that Mathematica assumes all numbers to be complex unless told otherwise. Consider the result of `FullSimplify[Solve[{k2 Cos[x] - k1 Sin[x] == 0}, x], {k1, k2, x} \[Element] Reals]` instead.

Comment: It is exactly what you are expecting, written in a different way. `ArcTan[x,y]` is ArcTan[y/x] with proper choice of sign. Check [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcTan.html) for details.

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you very much! By the way, I won't have any situation where I consider variables that are not real. Can I just make assumption that all variables are reals globally?

Comment: `Assuming[{{k1, k2} \[Element] Reals}, 
 Simplify[Solve[k2 Cos[x] - k1 Sin[x] == 0, x]]]` . you will still have a condition  because it is not specified that we are looking for Principal values (That is the `solution + 2Pi C[1]` part).

Comment: @Sumit Thank you so much. How to I specify I only want principal values?

Comment: @user42459 You can't quite make that assumption for any and all variables, but you may be interested in this: [How to tell Mathematica that the argument of a function is real?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95958/27951)

Answer (score 2):

To remove the condition just assume the condition

```
soln1 = Solve[k2 Cos[x] - k1 Sin[x] == 0, x] //
  Simplify[#, Element[C[1], Integers]] &
```

[image]

To look at the fundamental interval, set the arbitrary integer constant to zero

```
soln2 = Solve[k2 Cos[x] - k1 Sin[x] == 0, x] /. C[1] -> 0
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[x /. soln2],
 {k1, -10, 10}, {k2, -10, 10},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
 PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Simplifying the results

```
soln3 = soln2 // FullSimplify[#, Element[{k1, k23}, Reals]] &
```

[image]

Despite its appearance, the first function is real-valued, e.g.,

```
x /. soln3 /. {k1 -> 1, k2 -> 3} // FunctionExpand
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[x /. soln3],
 {k1, -10, 10}, {k2, -10, 10},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
 PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]