# How to treat indexed variables as Reals? Can they be symbolized?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, assumptions

First of all, this is quite related to [this question here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118955/21606), however the solution given there does not apply to my issue.

I am generating a huge symbolic matrix, which has many (on the order of 50-100) indexed parameters originating in various sums. All of my symbols and indexed variables are real, so I would like to make use of that when I for instance perform a `Conjugate` operation on the matrix.

See below minimal working example:

```
test = Exp[I*k[1]];
# + Conjugate[#] &@test
(* E^(-I Conjugate[k[1]]) + E^(I k[1]) *)
Refine[%, Assumptions -> k \[Element] Reals]
(* E^(-I Conjugate[k[1]]) + E^(I k[1]) *)
Refine[%, Assumptions -> k[1] \[Element] Reals]
(* E^(-I k[1]) + E^(I k[1])1 *)
```

An approach like `Refine[...,Assumptions->_Symbol ∈ Reals]` will also not work, since `Head[k[1]]` is `k`, not `Symbol`. The list of all indexed variables is not known in advance and changes as soon as I play with certain parameters, so I cannot just retrieve them once in order to get a full list and use this in `Assumptions`.

Is there a way to tell mathematica that all `Symbol`s and indexed variables are `Reals`? Presumably it can be done using `Symbolize` from the `Notation` package, but I don't know how (I have seen it for `Subscripts` but really want to avoid using them). How to deal with symbols is clear from the linked question, but achieving it for indexed variables is a myth for me right now.

Comment: Can you use `ComplexExpand`?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Right now, yes. But the size of my matrices will grow quite a lot in future work and also the "length" of each element. So I am unsure if `ComplexExpand` might take too long in those cases. I was thinking about using a rule like `Complex[a_,b_]:>Complex[a,-b]` instead of `Conjugate` but I have a feeling that this is not safe.

Comment: What are you going to do with the matrices? Look at them, solve equations involving them...?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer At first, it is mostly looking at them and transfering them to Matlab for further numerical simulations. However, depending on the numerical results, I might also try to work with the symbolic matrices in Mathematica which would for instance involve some series expansions and solving equations based on those matrices.

Comment: `Assumptions -> _k ∈ Reals`, or ``Assumptions -> (s_Symbol /; Context@s =!= "System`")[_Integer?
    Positive] ∈ Reals``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An approach like `Refine[...,Assumptions->_Symbol ∈ Reals]` will also not work, since `Head[k[1]]` is `k`, not `Symbol`.

You are almost there: just use a proper pattern to match objects with `Head` `k`. Here are several ways:

```
test = Exp[I*k[1]];
expr = # + Conjugate[#] &@test;

Refine[expr, Assumptions -> _k ∈ Reals]
Refine[expr, Assumptions -> k[_] ∈ Reals]
Refine[expr, Assumptions -> k[_Integer] ∈ Reals]
```

> ```
> E^(-I k[1]) + E^(I k[1])
>
> E^(-I k[1]) + E^(I k[1])
>
> E^(-I k[1]) + E^(I k[1])
> ```

(checked with *Mathematica* versions 11.2.0, 8.0.4 and 5.2).

---

> Is there a way to tell *Mathematica* that all `Symbol`s and indexed variables are `Reals`?

Here is a way to declare that every `Symbol` or indexed object is `Real`:

```
Refine[expr, Assumptions -> _Symbol[_Integer] ∈ Reals && _Symbol ∈ Reals]
```

> ```
> E^(-I k[1]) + E^(I k[1])
> ```

A more restrictive approach to declare that every indexed variable is `Real` is suggested by [jkuczm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/14303/jkuczm) in the [comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131778/how-to-treat-indexed-variables-as-reals-can-they-be-symbolized#comment357217_131778):

```
Refine[expr, 
 Assumptions -> (s_Symbol /; Context@s =!= "System`")[_Integer?Positive] ∈ Reals]
```

> ```
> E^(-I k[1]) + E^(I k[1])
> ```

It can easily be extended to `Symbol`s:

```
Refine[expr, 
 Assumptions -> ((s_Symbol[_Integer?Positive] | s_Symbol) /; 
     Context@s =!= "System`") ∈ Reals]
```

> ```
> E^(-I k[1]) + E^(I k[1])
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can `Symbolize` classes of expressions based on rules. For example,

```
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_", "_"]], WorkingForm -> StandardForm]
```

will declare any subscripted expression to be considered a symbol and be subsequently treated as such. Also see the tutorial [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/tutorial/NotationSymbolizeAndInfixNotation.html).

**Edit:**
Sorry, I realize I may have misunderstood your question. Do you want expressions such as `k[1]` to be considered symbols? If so, then I don't think that can be done. You may be able to construct some notation for certain types of expressions, but not in the way it appears from your original post, since that would require modifying core WL syntax.

Comment: Exactly, my idea for a solution was to symbolize `k[1]`. However, this is not mandatory... I thought it might be the easiest way to aim at declaring everything as real.