# Define the substitution procedure as a function

Tags: list-manipulation

We want to define a function of substitution (as a pure function) which can apply to a number or to a list. This desired function is as

```
/.{I -> -I, -I -> I}
```

However this work will do by `Conjugate`, but we do not want to use that.

For example: `list={I, 2, b, I b, -I b};`

`list/.{I -> -I, -I -> I}={-I, 2, b, -I b, I b}`; The desired format is `F[list]={-I, 2, b, -I b, I b};` This procedure even should be apply just for a number as `I/.{I -> -I, -I -> I}=-I`. How can we write F? For instant: `Map[/.{I -> -I, -I -> I}, list]` or `conj[# _] & = {I -> -I, -I -> I} /@ #`; which are written too bad.

Comment: `f = # /. {I -> -I, -I -> I} &;`

Comment: Kindly expand upon the problems you experience with `Conjugate` and symbols. You will get more help if you make your question as clear as possible. You have some typos (`./` needs to be `/.`)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I corrected the typos. Some of my questions are related to `Conjugate` but I am hopeless to use that correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me first point something important out before answering the question: 
I suspect that you want to "replace" `Conjugate` with an own function. However your approach as you presented it *won't* work. Just try `1+I/.I->-I` and observe the output (this is because complex numbers are atomic quantities).

Anyways, here's how you can create such a function:

```
conjugate1[expr_] := expr /. x_Complex :> Conjugate[x];
conjugate2[expr_] := expr /. Complex[a_, b_] :> Complex[a, -b];
```

You may then just do what you wish:

```
conjugate1[list]
conjugate2[list]
Map[conjugate1, list]
Map[conjugate2, list]
```

all return `{-I, 2, b, -I b, I b}` as output which is of course the same as `Conjugate[list]` *AS LONG AS* `b` is real! I want to remind you to bear in mind that this will not give the proper `Conjugate`ed result if any of the symbols can be complex.

Comment: In fact, I am sure that symbols are real. Unfortunately, `Conjugate` has some problems when we work with symbols.

Comment: @Irreversible If you are sure that all symbols are real you should be good to go with this approach. What are these "problems" you encounter when working with `Conjugate`? Check this (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118956/21606), maybe it helps a bit - if my suspicion about your issues is correct.