# How to define a real positive variable in mathematica

Tags: variable-definitions

Suppose I have a function $f(x)$.  I want *Mathematica* to treat $x$ as a real positive number, and hence to interpret $\sqrt{x^{2}}$ as $x$, for instance.  How to do that?

Comment: Assuming[x>0,f[x]] should solve your problem. You could also use $Assumptions command.

Comment: Depending on what computation you're doing, the answer might be there isn't a (convenient) way.  *Mathematica* applies `$Assumptions` sparingly, for instance, whenever `Simplify` is called and functions that have an `Assumptions` option.  I don't think you can get *M* to automatically simplify `Sqrt[x^2]` to `x` (barring overriding `Power`).  You would have to use something like `Simplify` to get the assumptions to have the desired effect. Often that is sufficiently acceptable.

Comment: Related: [How to tell Mathematica that the argument of a function is real?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96099/14303)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll use "code" in this answer to symbolize whatever you are doing, just in case it is more complex than just the function you mentioned.

One way to get Mathematica to do what you ask is by:

```
Assuming[x>0,
"code"
]
```

But as "code" gets bigger or starts to encompass more than one cell it becomes easier to use

```
$Assumptions = x > 0;
"code"
$Assumptions = True;
```

The last line is not strictly necessary, but it might be very important. It clears your assumptions, so that you may use the symbol x freely again. If you have more than one notebook in use at once I recommend using it.

Checkout the tutorials when in doubt (lots of good stuff there):

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html?q=%24Assumptions